# .NET Regex match space character when IgnorePatternWhitespace is on

Tags: .net, regex

I have a large regular expression and I've turned on IgnorePatternWhitespace so I can make it more readable.  My problem is that I want to match a literal space character.  What's the best way to do that?

An example:

```
Regex myRegex = new Regex(@"
  (?> <table[^>]*> ) # Find a table
  (?> .*?<tr> ) # Find the first row
  (?> .*?<th> ) # Find the first header column
  My phrase # Look for our key phrase
  etc.
", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

In the above example, "My phrase" should include a space.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It would appear that you can simply escape the space character with a backslash:

```
My\ phrase
```

Answer (score 11):

Use "\s" or "[ ]"

Comment: Use [ ] since \s will also match tabs and newlines.